# Calling a function in an iframe from a parent in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari, google-chrome

I'm trying to call a function, test(), of an iframe from the parent document using the code

```
subframe.test();
```

subframe refers correctly to the iframe, alert(subframe) returns [object HTMLIFrameElement], and the function runs in both IE7 and opera (9.23), but not firefox (3.0), chrome (3.0) or safari (3.03 beta windows). I assume these browsers support the functionality, so wondering if perhaps I'm using an incorrect call which IE and Opera support anyway, which wouldn't surprise me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I should answer for posterity - I solved the problem using subframe.contentWindow.test() .

Answer (score 0):

Is the domain of the parent document's source the same as that of the child iframe's? I believe FireFox requires that they are in order to do something like this.

Comment: Yes, they're in the same domain.

Comment: @wyatt - try `subframe.documentElement`

Comment: subframe.documentElement returns undefined for me. For reference, I solved it in the end using subframe.contentWindow.test();